# Famo.us - Dragging surface down triggers an event

Tags: famo.us

How would I go about creating a transition/event that is triggered when a surface is dragged down? I was looking at the 'Draggable' modifier but I don't think this is what I need. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a SidepanelLayout. You can drag the main surface to the right, and when a certain position or velocity threshold is reached, it triggers a transition to snap into place.

Check out [the gist](https://gist.github.com/markmarijnissen/62c810e70f308affd5d6) here.

These are the steps you need to take:

1. Create a surface
2. Create a Transitionable for y position
3. Create a modifier to modify surface position based on Transitionable
4. Pipe surface events to a GenericSync
5. When sync emits update events, set Transitionable to move surface
6. When sync emits end event, set Transitionable with an animation to end position

Does this provide you with enough pointers?